# Iis ReactJS supposed to reload whenever there is a change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning `ReactJS`, but I want to know if it's right that whenever I save a file, the browser reloads automatically before displaying the change. I want to know if that's how it's supposed to be or I am doing it wrong, I really thought it will change without refreshing the browser.

Ignore this part:

```
const BaseRouter = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={PostList} />
        <Route exact path='/:postID/' component={PostDetail} />
    </div>);
```

Comment: *"whenever I save a file"* - So you're over-writing the file during development?  Something else?  It's not really clear to me the specific action you're taking.  And is the entire page reloading?  Or just the component re-rendering?

Comment: Still in development, When i make a change and save, the entire page reloads, when I click a button on the page, it loads the page like a normal like

Comment: It reloads to reflect the updated changes then.  Part of create-react-app includes that feature.

Comment: OKay. But do you think after i have finished with it... when its ready and instances are created it wont be reloading for the users?

Comment: Not unless those users are also modifying the code in a development environment.

Comment: You mean as described on https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-start-or-yarn-start? Or something else? As for "when you're done", you would host it as a static bundle, rather than through a live-reloading dev server command.

Answer (score 0):

If you've setup the project with `react-create-app` it will reload the page by default.

However, generally speaking, there's a technique called ["Hot Module Replacement" (HMR)](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) which allows apply changes without full page reload.

HMR, however, have quite a few limitations which might make you chose using full page reload anyway.